# Xamarin droid app, could not find file /FORM_PROJECT_NAME.dll

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a PCL project (called SharedFeature) that is shared by iOS and Android project. It worked fine on both iOS and Android emulators. But it does not work on device. The error is: Could not find file "/SharedFeature.dll". Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which device - iOS, Android, both?  Is this a deployment error, a compile error, or a runtime error?  What is the specific error/exception that you're receiving?

Comment: both iOS and Android. It was runtime error. It happened when i clicked on the button that invokes class in the shared project.  From Android device the error was:  Could not find file "/SharedFeature.dll", in VS studio "application output", it was: [ViewRootImpl] sendUserActionEvent() mView == null.  iOS device had error "... SharedFeature.dll cannot be accessed".